# How to validate upload file only pdf

Tags: validation, file-upload, upload, codeigniter-3

I would like to validate file upload, the condition is file input can upload file if file input is empty, but if file input does not match the type of file setting then the error showing. How to make these error. if I using this script : `!$this->upload->do_upload('file')` and i let file input empty, certainly the error are showing.

this is my Config upload :

```
        $config['upload_path'] = '../../upload/file';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
        $config['file_name'] = 'file_'.time();
        $config['overwrite'] = true;
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){
            $respond['error'] = true;
            $respond['message'] = "Error Upload".$this->upload->display_errors();
        }
```

Comment: So you want to make a _pdf validation_  **only** if the user upload a file?

Comment: yes, although file input is empty

Answer (score 0):

You could add a condition, so it will only validate if there are uploaded file :

```
<?php

if ( $_FILES && $_FILES['file']['name'] ) 
{
    $config['upload_path'] = '../../upload/file';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
    $config['file_name'] = 'file_'.time();
    $config['overwrite'] = true;
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('file')){
        $respond['error'] = true;
        $respond['message'] = "Error Upload".$this->upload->display_errors();
    }

}
```

Comment: whats mean of $_FILES ?

Comment: The `$_FILES` is php superglobal variable which contains uploaded file data, it will contain data only if you upload a file. You could `var_dump()` it to see all of it content

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work perfectly for you

```
        $config['upload_path']      =   './uploads/;
        $config['allowed_types']    =   'pdf';
        $config['max_size']         =   0;
        $config['max_width']        =   0;
        $config['max_height']       =   0; 

       $config['file_name']        =   round(100,99); //make your file name random

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);

        if($this->upload->do_upload('file_name')){
            print $this->upload->data();                    
        }else{
          print $this->upload->display_errors();
        }
```